# Log4j FileAppender programmatically use a different time zone

Tags: java, log4j

Can `org.apache.log4j.FileAppender` be set to *log* a different time zone than the one the application is running? To be clear, I am not talking about adding a time zone to what is printed to the log, but rather, for the timestamp itself to *be* a different time zone.

For example, we use Wildfly as our application server, and everything in server.log shows up in local time. This is good.

When our application starts up however, we do `java.util.setDefault(TimeZonze.getTimeZone("UTC"));` This is so that all embedded devices across all clients can be stored and compared to each other from a common time reference.

This means that when we programmatically set up our FileAppender later on to log stuff to several different dynamically named log files, their timestamps are printed in UTC. But we want those logs generated from FileAppender to *also* be printed in local time.

Is there a way to do this?

Below is how we set up our FileAppender:

```
public void addFileAppender(String someDynamicName) {
    FileAppender appender = new FileAppender();
    appender.setName(someDynamicName);
    appender.setFile(getLogDir().getPath() + "/" + someDynamicName + ".log");
    appender.setLayout(new PatternLayout("%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %m%n"));
    appender.setThreshold(org.apache.log4j.Level.DEBUG);
    appender.setAppend(true);
    appender.activateOptions();
    Logger.getLogger(someDynamicName).addAppender(appender);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it’s a good idea to be changing the Locale after the application has started, even if it’s at the very start of your application? What if some other part of your code, or even another library, makes a static call to the Locale and then holds on it (or some formatter based on it)? It might be safer to pass it in as a JVM argument. I appreciate this doesn’t solve your problem.

Comment: Definitely not my call. Business decision / requirement by the managers who know oh so much. It's been like this for 10 years and doesn't seem to have caused any issues. Personally, I would have preferred to handle that in some non blanket way as well.